# How do I let a user use data from a csv file perform calculations with it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I'm quite new to coding and essentially all I want to do is to allow a user to create a csv file and input data to it, and then be able to view the data and perform calculations with it. I have got as far as allowing the user to create the csv file and input data to it, as below:

```
import csv

def filecreator():
    print("----------INPUT--DATA----------")
    filename = input("File Name: ")
    print("A file has been created named",filename,". csv")
    print("-------------------------------")




    with open(filename, 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
        w = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=' ')
        save = "y"
        while save == "y":
            drone = int(input("Drone Number: "))
            time = int(input("Time: "))
            temperature = input("Enter temperature: ")  
            windspeed = input("Enter windspeed: ")
            


            save = input("Would you like to save? Y/N: ")  
            if save.lower() == "y":
                w.writerow([drone, time, temperature, windspeed])   
                print("---Your data has been saved---")


        print("Program closed.")


userinput = input("Enter I to input data, V to view data or C to do calculations: ")

if userinput=="I" or "i":
    print("\nYou have chosen to input weather data to the program")
    filecreator()

elif userinput=="V" or "v":
    print("\nYou have chosen to view weather data.")

elif userinput=="C" or "c":
    print("\nYou have chosen to perform calculations with weather data.")
```

For context, it is a weather data collecting program, with data collected from drones, and I need to calculate weather patterns such as average temperature. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `if userinput=="I" or "i"` That is not the right way to check for multiple values.  Try `if userinput.lower() == "i"` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can do it Using a famous library called Pandas

Install pandas on your computer using pip or conda

command for pip

> pip install pandas

Command for Conda

> conda install pandas

Import Pandas in your files

> import pandas as pd
> data_frame = pd.read_csv("FILE_PATH/FILE_NAME.csv");

Then you can Apply any calculations on Data_frame variable:

Eg: Calculating Average of particular Column

> data_frame['column_name'].mean();

Sample :

```
import pandas as pd;
df = pd.read_csv("Salaries.csv");
df['BasePay'].mean();
```